# Angular5 application failing after production build with ng build --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I'm at a total loss as to how to debug this.

I've built an application with Angular 5 and it is running great during development with `ng serve --aot --progress=false --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Now I am ready to deploy to production. I'm running `ng build --prod --sm=false --aot --output-path=dist/client` and the build is successful.

I copy the client side files to the server and when I run in a browser I receive the following error.

FireFox:

```
TypeError: t[r] is undefined          main.1eda0feb0dddc7c4747b.bundle.js:1:791705
```

Chrome

```
main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
at n (main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1)
at Object.t.exports (main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1)
at n (main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1)
at Object.t.exports (main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1)
at n (main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1)
at Object.t.exports (main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1)
at n (main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1)
at Object.t.exports (main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1)
at n (main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.d8cd32d2ec09f8365918.bundle.js:1)
```

and if I go to the specific portion of the main bundle:

```
...return t[r].call(i.exports,i,i.exports,n),i.l...
```

How in the world do I debug this and figure out what is causing the problem?

Comment: Did it work before? Did you update som packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening a ticket with angular/cli and a user having a conversation on Gitter with the team it appears this is related to a cli dependency. Adding the flag of `--build-optimizer=false` should fix most cases. They are hoping to get it resolved with @angular/cli 1.6.5

Full conversation can be read at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9244#issuecomment-358828083

Comment: But I'm on angular CLI 1.6.8 and still facing the same issue

Comment: ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false 
this is the only thing working for me even in Angular cli version 1.6.8

Answer (score 0):

Using `--aot=false` helped in my case

UPD: This was a bug in Angular CLI. Fixed in version 1.6.6

Comment: surprisingly this seems to have removed the error on render. I'll some some additional testing and update my original post/answer with info. I would say this fixes it. need to find the cause of the --aot issue.

Comment: sorry meant to say I'll do some more testing and that this doesn't necessarily solve the problem just allows me to do a production build that works.

Comment: It appears that it was a bug in Angular CLI 1.6.4 and 1.6.5 (or to be more exact in `build-optimizer` package which is used by Angular CLI). 
It's fixed now in version 1.6.6 of CLI.

Answer (score -1):

we should not use `--aot=false` every time, because of which build create successfully but not work after deployment. better use the exact angular clit version in your global whatever you use in an application.

i solved this problem by changing my angular CLI version using the command

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@1.6.8
```

Check your package-lock.json for your angular version and change the version in above command.

Comment: yes, if you take a look at the accepted answer, it was a bug which was corrected.